# How to analyze quickly the code definition from a given code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Let's say I'm in a really huge project and am curious how this line works:

```
authorize! :read_pipeline_schedule, user_project
```

`authorize!` is supposed to be method name. Is it a private function in the class, or DSL provided from a parent block, or including, or declared in a gem? Or maybe none of them?

I was using grep to find internal code and Google for external code such as gems, however I guess it's useful if I can see the call stack of the method. `puts caller` is printing from the place where I am although it can not be used for analyzing the above case.

I'd like to know the best practice.

Comment: You can see some information (such as if it comes from a module) with `print method(:authorize!)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can grep your code and installed gems and, if name is unique enough, you'll quickly locate its definition and associated usages. However, if a name is a common one, like `call`, then this approach is useless.

Ruby is a dynamic language and, as such, is a nightmare for static analysis. You may *guess* where this comes from, but you just can't **know** for sure.

The only way to *know* is runtime introspection. So, in your example, put a breakpoint right before that line

```
binding.pry
authorize! :read_pipeline_schedule, user_project
```

You'll drop out to `pry` shell. Now you can do

```
show-source authorize!
```

And see where *exactly* this method is defined.

Comment: Re: using grep. I've been going through code that has several classes using the same names for methods, making it darn near impossible to figure out which of the particular methods are being called because the object isn't known. Only by stopping the runtime and observing the object itself is it possible to see what's really happening.

Comment: I just tried `binding.pry` and `show-source`. AMAZING! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ask the method itself:

```
method_object = method(:authorize!)

method_object.owner
# => returns module in which the method resides

method_object.source_location
# => returns file name and line number of source code where the method is defined
```

Note that `source_location` may return `nil` for methods which have no Ruby source code, e.g. dynamically generated methods or methods implemented in the interpreter internals (C functions in YARV, Java methods in JRuby, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I like `caller(0)`, `caller_locations`, and the ever-incredible `show-source`